# Change the format of the datepicker to weekday - material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**I want to change the format of the datepicker to weekday (Monday, Tuesday,..)** The default version of the datepicker format is `format="MM/dd/yyyy"` Is it possible to change it?

Source code:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Grid container justify="space-around">
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'change date',
          }}
        />
```

Comment: what you do mean by weekday, if you open calendar you want see only sunday monday instead of date?

Comment: No. I am trying to add recurring events to the calendar. Due to this, I want to get the weekday with the date that I select. For example, when I select 4 June 2020 from the date picker, I want to get the day 'Thursday' as a resource. After that, I add events on every Thursday after 4 June 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the format value of `KeyboardDatePicker` to `format="EE - MM/dd/yyyy"` show the weekdays with month/date/year. Moreover, if you want to change the format of `KeyboardDatePicker` you can refer to [here](https://date-fns.org/docs/format).Try this:

```js
<KeyboardDatePicker
  disableToolbar
  variant="inline"
  format="EE-MM/dd/yyyy"
  margin="normal"
  id="date-picker-inline"
  label="Date picker inline"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={handleDateChange}
  KeyboardButtonProps={{
    'aria-label': 'change date',
  }}
/>
```